# Circle under tangents meets incircle at same point on BC

Tags: geometry

> Inside $\triangle ABC$, let a circle $\omega$ be tangent to sides AB and AC, not touching BC.
> Tangents from B and from C to $\omega$ (different from the triangle sides) intersect at
> point X. Show that the incircle of triangle BCX and the incircle of triangle ABC
> touch BC at the same point.

Here is a fun JBMO problem that I came across. I know how to calculate the distance between that point that they both touch BC at and either $B$ or $C$, but I can't deal with the condition with the circle on top of the two tangent lines. The length condition doesn't seem to help in any way either.

This is a junior olympiad problem, so please give a synthetic solution, and make it elementary :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you wrote, esp "calculate the distance between that point that they both touch BC at and either $B$ or $C$" and "condition with the circle on top of the two tangent lines". Can you elaborate on what you're trying to express?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw an accurate diagram. In a non-competition setting, use geogebra to play around with the setup.
Observe that these 2 incircles touch on $BC$. That's a huge giveaway for what to track.

> One approach is to show that the corresponding tangency point has the same distance along line BC.
>  Let incircle of $ABC$ be tangent to $BC$ at $D_A$, then $CD_A = (AC +CB - BA )/2$.
>  Let incircle of $XBC$ be tangent to $BC$ at $D_X$, then $CD_X = (XC + CB -BX ) / 2$.

> It remains to show that $AC - BA = XC - BX$.

> Show this is true via side length chasing, and remember that "$\omega$ is the incircle of the quadrilateral $ABXC$".
>  (This is in quotation marks because that's not quite true when $ABXC$ is a concave quad, but the side length chasing still holds.)